# 500 Internal Server - Apache

Tags: php, linux, apache, web, apache2

My site frequently displays 500 Internal Server Error. Restarting apache, brings the site back to normal state. Other sites running on the same server does not have this issue. Apache error log have no information related to this. The apache loglevel of this site is set as "warn".

What may be the reason for this ?

My site is written on PHP and deployed in linux server.

Answer (score 0):

If you have suphp installed it might be e permissions problem - if its installed all the files need to have chmod set to 644 and all thefolders - 755

Answer (score 0):

Please check the folder necessary permissions. Then in index.php file add

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

to display error reports. So that you can find the error.

Comment: This is a good advice. But I don't think the PHP script will be able to display an error after apache terminates it with a 500 error.

Comment: @salman Actually some times apache server will show error as blank empty page or else it just shows "500 Internal server". But when you enable error reports it ll display the errors. so only i suggested this one.